# Why is partially summing terms of an infinite p-adic series unjustified?

Tags: divergent-series, p-adic-number-theory

Why is this unjustified?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$$
$$= \sum_{n=1}^p 1 +\sum_{n=p+1}^{p+p^2} 1 + \sum_{n=p+p^2+1}^{p+p^2+p^3} 1 + \cdots$$
$$=p+p^2+p^3+\cdots$$
$$ = \frac{p}{1-p}$$

Comment: Part of the issue is, let's say 1+1+1 = 3, but depending on how I sum it, it seems to be the difference between converging or not, sorta like a kinda internal riemann rearrangement theorem or something? Or maybe I'm over thinking it somehow here.

Comment: But shouldnt the last "$=$" only be true for $p\le1$?

Comment: JohnGlenn: The post has a tag "p-adic-number-theory". With respect to the $p$-adic metric, the third "=" is valid (because there actually $|p|<1$). Of course, if one works in the usual metric and $p\ge1$, that third "=" is not true either. (Also @Max Ft, maybe that is the reason for all the misunderstanding?)

Comment: In a sense this is not entirely unlike the following fallacy from calculus (i.e. convergence w.r.t.  the usual absolute value):
$$1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots=(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots=0.$$ In other words, you group terms in a way that produces a lot of cancellation. In your case the cancellation was not perfect, but it did produce small enough terms to allow you to sum them up.

Comment: Oh very nice, I really like that; brings it all together now in my mind.

Comment: @JohnGlenn The first line in equal to the second line iff p>=1 but as you said the last line is only true if p<1. That's it. Nothing else to prove right? what do you think?

Comment: @MaxFt Here the convergence is with respect to the $p$-adic metric, not the usual absolute value from calculus. So here $p$ is some unspecified prime number. In [the $p$-adic metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) the absolute value of $p$ is $|p|_p=1/p$. As that is $<1$ the geometric series $p+p^2+p^3+\cdots$ converges $p$-adically, and its sum is equal to $p/(1-p)$. That last step is valid. The error was earlier. Usual calculus of series of real numbers does not apply here, because $p$-adic numbers usually aren't real.

Comment: @MaxFt For example, in the 2-adic world we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n=0,$$ as well as
$$1+2+4+8+16+32+\cdots=\frac1{1-2}=-1.$$

Comment: Also @MaxFt, the first line is "equal to the second line" only w.r.t. the usual absolute value **and even then** only in the sense that both are not defined -- something better not expressed via "=". (Whereas in $p$-adic metric, the second actually is defined, the first one still isn't, so they are not equal in a stronger sense). I mean, in your line of reasoning, why don't you just say $1\ge1$, so the first line is undefined and cannot equal anything. (That's what you seem to argue about the third line, it's just that in $p$-adic analysis, that one actually does make sense as Jyrki explains.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand better. I am not familiar with $p$-adic theory. So the first line is equal to the second line in term of limit as stated. Is it also equal in term of partial sum? I mean if we only sum over a finite number of element is there still a similar equality in $p$-adic metric?

Comment: @MaxFt: The first line expresses a limit which does *not* exist (in any of the metrics considered), so I would not say it is "equal" to anything. The second and third line express a limit which *does* exist in the $p$-adic metric -- where this limit is equal to the fourth line. What do you mean by "equal in term of partial sum", and what should be equal to what here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whereas the second "=" is true in general (if "+..." is interpreted correctly), and the third "=" is true with respect to the $p$-adic metric, the first "=" lacks justification. It would be some "infinite associativity law" which simply does not exist if the series is not convergent.

To see things clearer, remember that convergence of a series $\sum a_n$by definition means convergence of the sequence of partial sums $s_n = \sum_{1}^n a_i$. Now in this example, $s_n =n$ which obviously does not converge in any $p$-adic metric. However you cleverly spotted a subsequence $s_p, s_{p+p^2}, s_{p+p^2+p^3}, ...$ which converges $p$-adically to $\frac{p}{p-1}$. Now *if* the sequence $s_n$ did converge, then it would converge to the same limit, but *it does not* -- it just happens to have this neat convergent subsequence.

Comment: I agree that this is the right answer, but it still feels wrong to me. I'll try to sleep on it and get over it I guess lol.

Comment: Another obviously converging subsequence is $s_p,s_{p^2},s_{p^3},\ldots$. That converges to $0$. So two different subsequences have different limits, again proving divergence :-). +1 was there since yesterday, of course.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Saw that one too, however it cannot be written so that it looks like partially summing terms. But we could do $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$$ $$"="$$  $$\sum_{n=1}^{p^{17}} 1 +\sum_{n=p^{17}+1}^{p^{17}+p^{34}} 1 + \sum_{n=p^{17}+p^{34}+1}^{p^{17}+p^{34}+p^{51}} 1 + \cdots$$
$$=p^{17}+p^{34}+p^{51}\cdots$$
$$ = \frac{p^{17}}{1-p^{17}}$$ (that's the subsequence $s_{p^{17}}, s_{p^{17}+p^{34}}, ...$) etc.

Comment: $p^{17}$. LOL! ${}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: My calculus students noticed recently that I use the parameter 17 a lot (when I want to throw in a random number; it somehow is more impressive, psychologically, than using a general "n" or "r" or "k"). Why 17? Because https://mathoverflow.net/a/285937/27465

Comment: You are not alone! The late professor Ennola (I took basic algebraic number theory from him) had a maxim about some obscure formulas: *If it works for $17$, it (most likely) works always.* :-)